# How to create 2D lists(matrix) with rows and columns being permutations

Tags: python, matrix

I want to iterate through all possibilities n* n matrix with rows and columns being permutations of 0 to n-1. For example one 3*3 matrix will be [[0,1,2],[1,2,0],[2,0,1]]. Here's what I have so far,

```
import itertools
l = list(itertools.permutations(range(0, n), n))
p = list(itertools.product(l, repeat=n))
for matrix in p:
   ...
```

But it obviously only has only rows as permutations and takes a huge amount of memory. I don't need to store all the possibilities but I just need to iterate and test each of them with some properties. n also doesn't need to be a big number, currently I aim at having it under 8.

I appreciate it a lot if you can answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Both `itertools.permutations` and `itertools.product` are iterators. Since you only need to store one "matrix" at a time, take advantage of this fact:

```py
for m in itertools.product(itertools.permutations(range(n), n), repeat=n):
    # test properties of m
```

Unfortunately this still requires storing the permutations over which the product is evaluated, which for `n=8` will be `40320` elements.